# Protecting / serving a file via readfile(), force download?

Tags: php, wordpress, readfile, force-download

I'm trying to make a simple script that does two things:

1. Serves up a file and hide's it's destination
2. Has a download counter

Now, I'm doing this in the wordpress environment, but this question isn't completely wordpress-related so I figured I would ask here.

Basically, the way I have it set up, currently, is I have a link that when you click it sets a `$_['GET']` which is then checked if is set. If it is set, the download file is served.

the link: `<a href="http://localhost:8888/fresh/?dl_id=01">Click here!</a>`'

the `$_['GET']` code: http://pastebin.com/93nD43gA

There is a bit of wordpress jargon in the code, but basically it's checking a download count user_meta and if it's > 0, `serveFile()` is called.

The main problem I'm having here is, if I click the link, `readfile()` loads the actual file contents INTO the window (garbled text). If I add a `target=_blank` to the `<a>` it opens a new browser window and loads the contents INTO the window.

This approach seemed to work perfectly fine when I was doing it as stand-alone php files. My main issue is that I need to keep the wordpress space so I can call functions, etc. associated with it.

I have tried using the `$_['GET']` on both the self page, another page with a custom template (the code in the pastebin above), and as a stand-alone php file. Both the first two options load the file INTO the window. The third doesn't preserve wordpress functions, even if I include `blog-header.php`.

Can anyone point me in to the right direction of how to get the file to force download and not load INTO the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate header for whatever the file type is.  For example, if `readfile` always serves, PDFs, it should be done like this:

```
// disable browser caching -- the server may be doing this on its own
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
//forces a download
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.pdf');
readfile($file);
```

Keep in mind that `header` only works if you have not sent any data in the request at all including whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I was wondering if that was the issue. I'll give this a look and report back.

Comment: I'm serving a rar, for the moment. It was working fine with octet-stream (have also tried x-rar-compressed) with a standalone php file. However if I try to do the same thing within Wordpress it outputs into the body of the site. I can't link to another page, the same page, or a stand-alone php file from within Wordpress and get the file to force dl. I read maybe setting some .htaccess things may help. I'm at a loss.

Comment: @tr3online look at the output of the page with `readfile` commented out.  Is there any output at all?  Also look at the headers that get sent.

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the fact that wordpress sends headers. My standalone php works completely fine with a `$_GET['dl_id'] = 1. When I try to include `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` I get an `Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)`. If I try to inclue the $_GET/force on another WP page, I get `Warning: Cannot modify header information` and the file outputs to the body. I can't for the life of me figure out how to make this work. Appreciate the help thusfar

Answer (score -2):

The 'garbled' text is what you want however besides that you have to set a mime. This can be accomplished by simply setting a header, e.g. `header("Content-Type: image/png");`

If the file mimes will vary (e.g. pdf, doc, png, etc) you should look into finfo extension. With it you can get the full and correct mime of the file

```
<?php
$finfo = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime = $finfo->file('path/to/file', FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
header("Content-Type: $mime");
```

As noted - headers can be set only if no write to output has been done (no echo's, print, etc. [Output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) could help you here).